# Accessing Struct in Header file

Tags: c

I have this defined in my header file:

```
typedef struct Code {
   char *data;
   unsigned short size;
} Code;
```

And these two in my .c file:

```
typedef struct MemBlock {
   char data[BLOCK_SIZE];
   int bytesUsed;
   struct MemBlock *next;
} MemBlock;

typedef struct CodeSet {
   Code *codes;
   MemBlock *memBlock;
   int size;
   int index;
} CodeSet;
```

I am trying to set the data in Code with something like:

```
mySet->codes[mySet->index]->size = 1;
```

but I get errors everytime I try to use -> after I put codes[]. What would the correct way be to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `->` to access members in pointers to `struct`. Since an array dereferenced isn't a pointer, it should be accessed with `.` instead of `->`.

Hence the correct syntax would be : `mySet->codes[mySet->index].size = 1;` since `codes[]` is an array and not a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`mySet->codes[mySet->index]` is not a pointer, it *is* a `struct Code`.

Use `mySet->codes[mySet->index].size`.